# Powershell script for processing pngs via exe parameters while maintaining source file structure

Tags: windows, powershell, png, layout, image-processing

I'm currently working on a personal project where I need to resize tens of thousands of png files. I know little to nothing about scripting, PS or programming (I'm a graphic artist)

I'm using a piece of software called [ImageResizer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/2dimagefilter/wikis/ImageResizer.wiki) that resizes images.

This software has command line parameters. The parameters I'm using are:

```
/resize auto "XBR 2x <NoBlend>"
```

which takes my image and uses an xBRx2 algorithm to double its size. It's this output that I need.

In fact, I have a batch file I grabbed from the software's Github that does exactly what I need it to do, but only for a single image. This is it, for reference:

```
@echo off 
for %%F in (Input*.*) do ImageResizer-r129.exe /load "%%F" /resize auto "XBR 2x <NoBlend>" /save "Output\%%~nF%%~xF"
```

Here's my dilemma. I have, as I mentioned, tens of thousands of these images. And you might be thinking "well, that cmd can do that"...

Except, these pngs are nested in a rather extensive subdirectory layout... and my output folder needs to maintain this same subdir layout as the input in order to work for what I need it to.

So, to explain what I need more clearly...

I have an INPUT folder. In this folder are several sub folders. And in each of those folders are more folders... how far it goes and the names of these folders varies. Eventually, at the end of each 'branch' are my pngs that I need my software to process.

So, my input folder looks kinda like this:

L Input
L_ chisel
L__ textures
L___ items
L____ one.png
L____ two.png
L___ models
L____ one.png
L____ two.png
L_ artifacts
L__ textures
L___ items
L____ groupOne
L_____ one.png
L_____ two.png
L____ groupTwo
etc

As you can tell from my example, there isn't a uniform naming structure, and from what little I know about scripting, a recursive switch is needed to grab all of the pngs.

All of the PNGs from this Input folder need to be passed through the ImageResizer.exe with my parameters.

Then, the processed PNGs need to output to an Output folder with the SAME subdir layout as the Input...
so, **Input/chisel/textures/items/one.png** needs to /save to **Output/chisel/textures/items/one.png** and so on for every png in my Input folder.

Alternatively, the script could just overwrite the original image from the Input folder. Either way accomplishes the same goal.

Here's my current PS script, which my in-law wrote, but wasn't able to complete.
http://pastebin.com/fveGJkRJ

Any help is GREATLY appreciated, as there's about ~18,000 pngs I need to process like this. 
I started to just copy and paste my batch script over and over, replacing each input and output with each file path, but that was eating up way too much time.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help with Powershell but look for something equivalent to *nix' "find" command, for which the task would be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a powershell script which does what you want.
As I have a problem with the args and quoting (and no time) it generates necessary folders and a batch file with all the args for ImageResizer-r129.exe, you will have to execute seperately.

```
$ImgRes= "ImageResizer-r129.exe"
$Input = "G:\Rebirth Gaming\ImageResizer\input\"
$output= "G:\Rebirth Gaming\ImageResizer\Output\"

$Len = $Input.Length

Set-Location $Input

Get-ChildItem *.png -file -recurse|
  ForEach {
    $OutPath = $Output+$($_.DirectoryName.Substring($Len))
    If (!(Test-Path $OutPath)) {MkDir $OutPath}
    "$ImgRes /load `"$_`" /resize auto `"XBR 2x <NoBlend>`" /save `"$OutPath\$($_.Name)`" "
} | Out-File $($Output+"Resize.cmd")
```